# Is there a way to search NetSuite Classification records by external id list via SOAP?

Tags: netsuite

I'm trying to check whether the data from the database exist on the NetSuite. I want to extract an external id list (called p_externals) from database and then search Classification records from NetSuite via SOAP by using this external id list (called p_externals) as parameters. I have gone through the Netsuite docs, but I can't find any method to achieve this goal. Could anyone help me? Thanks for any information in advance.

By the way, it's my first question asked on stackoverflow, and I'm not familiar with the method of asking questions, any advice on this aspect is also welcome, thank you!

Comment: Hi Don, welcome to Stack Overflow! What does p_externals relate to in NetSuite? I'm assuming the database you mention is external to NetSuite and the p_externals is either the internal ID of an object on NetSuite or it is the document number(Displayed at the top of any NetSuite records).

Comment: Also, I'm unsure what you are referring to as "Classification records". Are you referring to the classification of orders by Subsidiary, Department and Location?

Comment: @Charl Thanks for you warm welcome and instant reply. I should not say anything called p_externals in my description. In fact, it doesn't really exist but only a name I gave temporarily for description. For  "Classification records", I'm referring to the  http://www.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2017_2/schema/record/classification.html?mode=package , should I called it entity or something else?

Comment: @Charl I have misunderstood that the query field called externalId for [ClassificationSearchBasic] (http://www.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2017_2/schema/search/classificationsearchbasic.html?mode=package) can only be a single record, but in fact, it can be a record list,  and I can use ClassificationSearchBasic to query by a external_id record list and fix this problem now. Thanks for you help all the same!

Comment: <platformMsgs:searchRecord xsi:type="listAcct:ClassificationSearch">
<listAcct:basic>
 <platformCommon:externalId operator="anyOf">
  <searchValue externalId=‘some_4' type='classification'  />
  
  <searchValue externalId=’some_5’ type='classification'  />
 </platformCommon:externalId>
</listAcct:basic>
    
</platformMsgs:searchRecord> The main SOAP request is above.